# Linking C files with a pre-built static library and compile the Swift project in Xcode

Tags: ios, c, swift, objective-c, bridging-header

I am new to iOS development. I have ample experience with Android Development.

In Android, I have a bunch of pre-built C static libraries. I also have C source code for another component. I build with the help of Android.mk in Android. As a part of the make file, I build a shared library(.so) by linking the static libraries and in turn use with JNI.

The following is a sample code in Android.mk

```
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)

    LOCAL_MODULE:= module_name

    LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/filepath/include

    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/filePath/filename1.c
    LOCAL_SRC_FILES:= $(LOCAL_PATH)/filePath/filename2.c

    LOCAL_LDLIBS:= -lm

    LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES:= static_lib1 static_lib2 ssl crypto

    include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I am porting the same project to iOS. SO, I am trying to use the same C source code and prebuilt C static libraries.

I have placed the files in Linked libraries in Build Phases but not use. I have read about module map, swift package manager, bridging header but not very clear.

Can anyone kindly help me with step by step process of this linking with the swift code?

Thank you